# Can I get a time-lapse camera for under $150?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, timelapse

I enjoy making time-lapse pictures with my Coolpix s550 and software.  However, the shortest interval for the s550 is 30 seconds.  I would like to know if there is a camera for under $150 that has shorter time intervals... perhaps ~5 second intervals or less?

Comment: Webcam + computer you already have?

Comment: Thanks, that might be practical for a couple situations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about one of the cheap Canon PowerShots with [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) installed?

Answer (score 6):

Brinno make a specialized time-lapse camera for $149 Sold by [Photojojo](http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/time-lapse-camera/) and others

- weather resistant (don't have to risk your SLR getting soaked)
- has normal and macro lens setting macro is about 19" or .5m
- six standard time settings of 1 minute, 5 minutes, 30 minutes, 1, 4 and 24 hours
- one custom time setting you can program anywhere between 5 seconds and 12 hours

battery life (4 AA)

- @5 second setting, will capture 28000 frames over 38 hours
- @24 hour setting, will capture 200 frames over 200 days

Comment: Cool product. I like that it is weather resistant. However, Photojojo says that it has "6 easy frame interval settings from 1 minute to 24 hours."

Comment: It has standard intervals of 1m, 5m, 30m, 1h, 4h and 24h. There is also a custom setting, which you can alter via a program when it's connected to your computer via a USB, and that can be set from 5 seconds to 24 hours.  I'll update the answer with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a lot of video cameras have a timelapse option built in.

I have one from Samsung (I can't remember the model number) depending on the quality of the photos you need, a video camera may be suitable.